# Toggle tooltip text

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tooltip, toggle

Basically my issue is that my tooltip won't change text on toggle. I have a page with expand/collapse functionality. Normally, when you hover over the up arrow, the title tag will say collapse panel. When you click the arrow button to collapse the div panel, the img changes (now the arrow will point down and the title tag should change to expand panel). This works and the title changes WITHOUT tooltips. When tooltips are added, the text doesn't change. I believe you have to destroy and create a new tooltip on click but I'm not sure how to do this.  He's my code, thanks in advance.

```
$("img.toggle1").click(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("panel1").style.display != "none") { // is the div hidden?
    $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-down.png");
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Expand this section");
     }
  else{ // is the div showing?
    $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-up.png");
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Collapse this section");
    $('div#header1').addClass('headerBarFirstOff');
  }
    $("div.panel1").slideToggle("slow");

  });
```

So update with the destroy/create method. I can get the tooltip to change to expand on the first click, but it stays as "expand". I used this:

```
$("img.toggle1").click(function(){
  if (document.getElementById("panel2").style.display != "none") {
    $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-down.png");
    $(document).tooltip("destroy"); //here's the change, the tooltip toggles once
    $(document).tooltip(); //here's the change, the tooltip toggles once
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Expand this section");
     }
  else{
    $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-up.png");
    //$(document).tooltip("destroy"); //doesn't work here
    //$(document).tooltip(); //doesn't work here
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Collapse this section");
  }
```

Also, I have checkboxes (that hide/show specific panels) and buttons that open or close all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input.togglePanel1").click(function(){
  if($(".togglePanel1").length == $(".togglePanel1:checked").length) { 
    $("div.panel1").slideDown("slow");
    } else {  
    $("div.panel1").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
$("input.togglePanel2").click(function(){
  if($(".togglePanel2").length == $(".togglePanel2:checked").length) { 
    $("div.panel2").slideDown("slow");
    } else {  
    $("div.panel2").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });
$("input.togglePanel3").click(function(){
  if($(".togglePanel3").length == $(".togglePanel3:checked").length) { 
    $("div.panel3").slideDown("slow");
    } else {  
    $("div.panel3").slideUp("slow");
    }
  });

$("img#closeAll").click(function(){
    $("div.panel1").slideUp("slow");
    $("div.panel2").slideUp("slow");
    $("div.panel3").slideUp("slow");
    $("div.panel4").slideUp("slow");
    $("div.panel5").slideUp("slow");
  });
$("img#openAll").click(function(){
    $("div.panel1").slideDown("slow");
    $("div.panel2").slideDown("slow");
    $("div.panel3").slideDown("slow");
    $("div.panel4").slideDown("slow");
    $("div.panel5").slideDown("slow");
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set tooltip text manually using the `uiTooltipTitle` data attribute

```
$("img.toggle1").click(function(){
  var ishidden = $('#panel1').is(':hidden');
  var src = ishidden ? "images/expander-down.png" : "images/expander-up.png"
  var title = ishidden ? "Expand this section" : "Collapse this section";
  $("img.toggle1")
           .attr("src", src);
  $("img.toggle1")
           .attr("title", title)
           .data('uiTooltipTitle', title);      
  $("div.panel1").slideToggle("slow");

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SHBWW/

Using if/else

```
$("img.toggle1").click(function(){
    if($('#panel1').is(':hidden')){
        $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-down.png");
        $("img.toggle1")
           .attr("title", "Expand this section")
           .data('uiTooltipTitle', "Expand this section");  
    }else{
        $("img.toggle1").attr("src", "images/expander-up.png");
        $("img.toggle1")
           .attr("title", "Collapse this section")
           .data('uiTooltipTitle', "Collapse this section");  
    }       
    $("div.panel1").slideToggle("slow");    
  });
```

Comment: The tooltips are toggling, but it seems to be one click behind. The first click doesn't make a change to the text or the button. The rest do.

Comment: Mines is the same as the if else.. but I'll make one with the if else

Comment: Got it! The exclamation mark  var ishidden =! $('#panel1').is(':hidden'); needed to be added. Thanks wirey!

Comment: ah ok .. you wanted the opposite.. you can do the `!` or use `.is(':visible')`

Comment: Genious!I also have buttons that close all panels, and check boxes that hide panels. How can I implement the img and title change here? Question updated.

Comment: You want this change to be universal with all your elements?  Sorry, I'm not fully understanding what you want.  If you can update/create the jsfiddle.net and explain what problem you are having I can probably walk you through it

Comment: The jsfiddle isn't working for me, but I'll do my best to explain. On my page, there are panels of information that you can collapse from that section, that is working beautifully and toggling as it should. Along with that though, under the header at the top of the page I have two other ways to close/open the panels. Buttons for "open all" panels and "close all" panels and checkboxes for each individual panel. When you click the checkbox beside the text "panel 1", it will expand or collapse only panel 1 and so on.

Comment: This functionality is all working (on my page, not the fiddle), but the img and title isn't toggling on click of the checkboxes or the open all/close all buttons.

Comment: @triplethreat77 oh ok.. I'm just trying to see how those elements are related to the one we just worked on..  I don't see the relation because we were working on `.toggle` classes and now these are `.panel` classes...  so should the title/image be changed depending on each div panel?

Comment: Yes. If the panel is expanded or collapsed with the arrow click, I need the arrow img to change, along with it's title and the corresponding checkbox title. If you click the checkbox, I need the checkbox title (example, if it's checked it will read "collapse this section")to change along with the corresponding panel arrow img and title. If you click the open all or close all icons, it needs to change each panel img and title.

Comment: Ah ok.. Trying to picture everything in my head.. I think I get where you're going now..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23238/discussion-between-wirey-and-triplethreat77)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img.toggle1").click(function(){
  if ($("#panel1").is(":visible")) { 
    //do something
    $("img.toggle1").removeAttr('title');
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Expand this section");
  }
  else{
    //do something
    $("img.toggle1").removeAttr('title');
    $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Collapse this section");
  }
});
```

Comment: That isn't working. My toggling is working perfectly fine, just the jquery tooltip won't update. $("img.toggle1").attr("title", "Expand this section"); Like I used above won't update the jquery tooltip, just the normal html title tags. I need a way to destroy the old jquery tooltip and create a new one with the toggle text.

Comment: @triplethreat77: Is the tooltip the default browser tooltip? Or is it a plugin which uses the `title` attribute at initialization(page load). You can try using `.removeAttr('title')`

Comment: It is the jquery that uses the title attribute and adds fancy css. Like I stated above, the default browser toggles just fine. If I place .removeAttr('title') in the code, my jquery tooltip won't show at all.

Comment: @triplethreat77: Yes, the fancy CSS needs to be undone and redone everytime. You could probably check the plugin docs itself. It would most likely have something to switch between `on` and `off` states.

Comment: I'm making progress and updated my question. Still not perfect though.